# Can't find the error in my Arraylist Flight Seating Plan

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, netbeans

So I have a code that creates a flight seating plan, when you press a button it turns red and changes the text to red after asking for a first name and last name, outputing "firstName" + "lastName" + "has been assigned to seat " + seat + "!""

it will then take that info and add it to the flight manifest which can be sorted by name or seat number.

the waitlist can have people added to and removed from as the user chooses.

My problem is that I don't know what's wrong with it. When I'm on Chart (the main class) none of the buttons work but there's no error message. If someone could read it over and point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Chart

```
   /*
    * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
    * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
    */
   package air.canada;

   import java.io.File;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.io.FileWriter;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Locale;

   /**
    *
    * @author sprince
    */
       public class Chart extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   
           //Added Generic Arraylist of Type Seat
           ArrayList<Seat> allSeats;
           File nameSave;
    
    /**
     * Creates new form Chart
     */
    
    public Chart() {
    initComponents();
    }
    
    //Added Function to write passengers list in file
    public void writeNamesInFile(ArrayList<Seat> allSeats) {
        
        nameSave = new File("nameList.txt");
        
        try {
            
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(nameSave, true);
            
            String strOutput = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < allSeats.size(); i++) {
                strOutput = strOutput + allSeats.get(i).getFirstName() + "\t" + allSeats.get(i).getLastName() + "\t" + allSeats.get(i).getSeat() + "\n";
            
            }
            
            fw.write(strOutput);
            fw.close();
        
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
    
    //add details in arraylist
    public void addSeat(String firstName, String lastName, String seatNameNumber) {

    //Create seat object
    Seat seat = new Seat();

    //set firstname lastname and seat
    seat.setFirstName(firstName);
    seat.setLastName(lastName);
    seat.setSeat(seatNameNumber.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));

    //add seat to arraylist
    allSeats.add(seat);
    
    }

    //Get all Seats that will return arraylist
    public ArrayList<Seat> getAllSeats() {
        return allSeats;
        
    }

    public void setAisle(javax.swing.JLabel aisleLabel, String aisleNo) {
        aisleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); 
        aisleLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        aisleLabel.setText(aisleNo);
    }

    public void setButtons(javax.swing.JButton jButton, String btnText) {
        jButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton.setText(btnText);
    }

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void buttonActionPerformedCommon(javax.swing.JButton btn, java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt, String seat) {

    //get first name
    String firstName = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your first name.", "Information Required", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    
    // if input is empty, exit
    if (firstName.isEmpty()) {
        
    } else {
        
        System.out.println(firstName);

        //get last name
        String lastName = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your last name.", "Information Required", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        // if input is empty, exit
        if (lastName.isEmpty()) {

        } else {

            System.out.println(lastName);
            
            //output, ___ has been assigned to seat ____
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, firstName + " " + lastName + " has been assigned to seat " + seat + "!", "YAY", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            //change colour of button
            btn.setBackground(Color.red);
            //keep text black
            btn.setForeground(Color.black);
            //change text to X
            btn.setText("X");

            //ADDED
            addSeat(firstName, lastName, seat);

            while (btn.isSelected()) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to remove " + firstName + " " + lastName + " form " + seat + "? ", "Replace?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void exitBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    
    //exit program
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to exit?", "Exit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);}
        
}                                       

private void manifestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     
    //Open Manifest
    //p2 = plan 2
    Manifest p2 = new Manifest(allSeats);
    //get names
    writeNamesInFile(allSeats);
    //display frame
    p2.show();
   
}                                        

private void waitlistActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    //Open Manifest
    //p3 = plan 3
    Waitlist p3 = new Waitlist();
    //display frame
    p3.show(); 
         
}                                        

public void checkFile() {
    try {
        if (nameSave.exists() == false) {
            nameSave.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Chart().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton a1;
private javax.swing.JButton a10;
private javax.swing.JButton a2;
private javax.swing.JButton a3;
private javax.swing.JButton a4;
private javax.swing.JButton a5;
private javax.swing.JButton a6;
private javax.swing.JButton a7;
private javax.swing.JButton a8;
private javax.swing.JButton a9;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle1;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle10;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle2;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle3;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle4;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle5;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle6;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle7;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle8;
private javax.swing.JLabel aisle9;
private javax.swing.JButton b1;
private javax.swing.JButton b10;
private javax.swing.JButton b2;
private javax.swing.JButton b3;
private javax.swing.JButton b4;
private javax.swing.JButton b5;
private javax.swing.JButton b6;
private javax.swing.JButton b7;
private javax.swing.JButton b8;
private javax.swing.JButton b9;
private javax.swing.JButton c1;
private javax.swing.JButton c10;
private javax.swing.JButton c2;
private javax.swing.JButton c3;
private javax.swing.JButton c4;
private javax.swing.JButton c5;
private javax.swing.JButton c6;
private javax.swing.JButton c7;
private javax.swing.JButton c8;
private javax.swing.JButton c9;
private javax.swing.JLabel chartLbl;
private javax.swing.JButton d1;
private javax.swing.JButton d10;
private javax.swing.JButton d2;
private javax.swing.JButton d3;
private javax.swing.JButton d4;
private javax.swing.JButton d5;
private javax.swing.JButton d6;
private javax.swing.JButton d7;
private javax.swing.JButton d8;
private javax.swing.JButton d9;
private javax.swing.JButton e1;
private javax.swing.JButton e10;
private javax.swing.JButton e2;
private javax.swing.JButton e3;
private javax.swing.JButton e4;
private javax.swing.JButton e5;
private javax.swing.JButton e6;
private javax.swing.JButton e7;
private javax.swing.JButton e8;
private javax.swing.JButton e9;
private javax.swing.JButton exitBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton f1;
private javax.swing.JButton f10;
private javax.swing.JButton f2;
private javax.swing.JButton f3;
private javax.swing.JButton f4;
private javax.swing.JButton f5;
private javax.swing.JButton f6;
private javax.swing.JButton f7;
private javax.swing.JButton f8;
private javax.swing.JButton f9;
private javax.swing.JButton g1;
private javax.swing.JButton g10;
private javax.swing.JButton g2;
private javax.swing.JButton g3;
private javax.swing.JButton g4;
private javax.swing.JButton g5;
private javax.swing.JButton g6;
private javax.swing.JButton g7;
private javax.swing.JButton g8;
private javax.swing.JButton g9;
private javax.swing.JButton h1;
private javax.swing.JButton h10;
private javax.swing.JButton h2;
private javax.swing.JButton h3;
private javax.swing.JButton h4;
private javax.swing.JButton h5;
private javax.swing.JButton h6;
private javax.swing.JButton h7;
private javax.swing.JButton h8;
private javax.swing.JButton h9;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu10;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu11;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu12;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu6;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu7;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu8;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu9;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
       private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
       private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar3;
       private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar4;
       private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar5;
       private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar6;
       private javax.swing.JButton manifest;
       private javax.swing.JButton waitlist;
       // End of variables declaration                   
   }
```

Comment: Believe it or not, one of the most important methods which is related to your question is the `initComponents()` method. It will determine if the `buttonActionPerformedCommon` event handler was properly applied to each of your buttons. The only thing that is displayed in your post related to the `initComponents()` is the `pack()` method and the closing curly brace so basically, the entire `initComponents()` method is missing from your example code.

Comment: It went over the character limit so I removed it, It is in the actual code

Comment: I've been over it and could find no errors

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess at what is going on because your `initComponents()` method is missing from the supplied code. If nothing is happening when a seat button is clicked up then we can obviously come to some conclusion that the `buttonActionPerformedCommon()` method is not getting called when a seat button is selected. At this point I can only suggest the following which I would like you to **try**...

**-: Make a backup of your application :-**

Create an *Inner Class* Within your **Chart** class and name it **SeatingActionListener**, for example:

```
public class Chart extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   
    // Arraylist of Type Seat
    public static ArrayList<Seat> allSeats;
    
    Public static File nameSave;
    

    // Constructor
    public Chart() {
        initComponents();
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------
    // .....   All The Rest Of Your Chart Class Code   .....
    // -----------------------------------------------------
    
    // Inner Class (SeatingActionListener):
    class SeatingActionListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getSource() instanceof javax.swing.JButton) {
                javax.swing.JButton button = (javax.swing.JButton) evt.getSource();
                String seatNumber = button.getActionCommand();

                /* Call the `buttonActionPerformedCommon()` method.
                   Notice how this method now only has two parameters 
                   instead of three. The `evt` ActionEvent parameter
                   wasn't doing anything anyways. It really shouldn't
                   be required. Who hey, who knows...you may need it
                   need for something in which case you can just add
                   the parameter back in if you like.             */
                buttonActionPerformedCommon(button, seatNumber);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Declare this listener within the members area of your **Chart** class, for example:

```
public class Chart extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Arraylist of Type Seat
    public static ArrayList<Seat> allSeats;

    Public static File nameSave;

    private SeatingActionListener seatingActionListener;

    // -----------------------------------------------------
    // .....   All The Rest Of Your Chart Class Code   .....
    // -----------------------------------------------------


}
```

You can actually use the above listener for any component that can utilize an Action Listener. You just need to sort out which component has fired the **actionPerformed** event with the `evt.getSource()` method.

Now, **make sure** each JButton has the `actionCommand` property set to the very same text as what was supplied to the `text` property.

Finally, *inside* your **Chart** class Constructor, ***under*** the call to the `initComponents()` method, add this code:

```
public Chart() {
    initComponents();

    seatingActionListener  = new SeatingActionListener();

    /* You can quickly see why using a JButton Array 
       would be soooooooo much better!            */
    a1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    a10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    b1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    b10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    c1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    c10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    d1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    d10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    e1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    e10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    f1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    f10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    g1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    g10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    h1.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h2.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h3.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h4.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h5.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h6.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h7.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h8.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h9.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);
    h10.addActionListener(seatingActionListener);

    /* Please consider using a JButton[] Array :/  */
}
```

**The tweaked buttonActionPerformedCommon() method:**

You can replace your current method with this one:

```
private void buttonActionPerformedCommon(javax.swing.JButton btn, String seat) {
    //get first name
    String firstName = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Please enter your first name.", "Information Required", 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    // if input is empty, exit
    if (firstName.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(firstName);

    //get last name
    String lastName = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Please enter your last name.", "Information Required", 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    // if input is empty, exit
    if (lastName.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(lastName);

    //output, ___ has been assigned to seat ____
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, firstName + " " + lastName 
                   + " has been assigned to seat " + seat + "!", "YAY", 
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //change colour of button
    btn.setBackground(Color.red);
    //keep text black
    btn.setForeground(Color.black);
    //change text to X
    btn.setText("X");

    //ADDED
    addSeat(firstName, lastName, seat);

    // This look suspicious... does it work?
    while (btn.isSelected()) {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to remove " 
                  + firstName + " " + lastName + " form " + seat + "? ", "Replace?", 
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Now save and Run your application.